# is it possible to bend a slider (html css)

Tags: jquery, html, css, slick.js

Hello i currently have a slick slider that is looking looking this:

[image: slick planets slider]

is there a way to achieve the following:
[image: bet slick slider]

I've tried with the corner-radius property but i was not able to obtain the desired result.
I want the center slider(planet) to look bigger and the rest of them to be smaller as they reach the margins.
I've thought that there is some way with the css transform but I didn't found any.
here is my current slider code:

```js
// planets slick slider
$('.planets-slider').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 7,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  centerMode: true,
  arrows: false,
  initialSlide: 3,
  swipeToSlide: true
});
```

```css
.planets-slider {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 80%;
  margin-top: 4vh;
  margin-left: 5rem;
  border-radius: 25%!important;
}

.slick-list {
  padding: 50px 0!important;
  outline: none !important;
}

.slick-slide {
  outline: none !important;
}

.slick-center {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.7);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.7);
  transform: scale(1.7);
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="planets-slider">
  <div><img src="images/planets/mercury.png" alt="mercury"></div>
  <div><img src="images/planets/venus.png" alt="venus"></div>
  <div><img src="images/planets/earth.png" alt="earth"></div>
  <div><img src="images/planets/mars.png" alt="mars"></div>
  <div><img src="images/planets/jupiter.png" alt="jupiter"></div>
  <div><img src="images/planets/saturn.png" alt="saturn"></div>
  <div><img src="images/planets/uranus.png" alt="uranus"></div>
  <div><img src="images/planets/neptune.png" alt="neptune"></div>
  <div><img src="images/planets/pluto.png" alt="pluto"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @RickardElimää thanks but not exactly, the fish eye is not what I want, in my case I want the center slider In slick to be the biggest and the rest of them smaller and smaller as they reach the margin.

Comment: Have you tried using  CSS's `skew` property?

Comment: @meDeepakJain skew I've tried but can't achieve this using it.

Comment: Will you plz attach a screenshot you tried using `skew`? Also, mention the code you used.